# Get max value of property in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I am trying to get the max value of all the wins properties in an object. Here is a shortened example of the object, of which I am trying to get the max value of the wins props, which would be 11.

```
var coach_wins = {
  "player1": [
    {
      year: 2015,
      wins: 6
    },
    {
      year: 2016,
      wins: 6
    }
  ],
  "player2": [
    {
      year: 2015,
      wins: 11
    },
    {
      year: 2016,
      wins: 6
    }
  ]
};
```

Currently I am counting the length of the object and then using a for loop to loop through the object and get the keys:

```
coach_wins[Object.keys(coach_wins)[i]];
```

then do this again and store the values of each wins value;

Is there a more efficient way?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want it over all, or per player?  Should the wins per player be summed before comparing different players?

Comment: @taplar I've edited the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var coach_wins = {
  "player1": [
    {
      year: 2015,
      wins: 6
    },
    {
      year: 2016,
      wins: 6
    }
  ],
  "player2": [
    {
      year: 2015,
      wins: 11
    },
    {
      year: 2016,
      wins: 6
    }
  ]
};

var max = Object.values(coach_wins) //get all the values of the object
  .reduce(function(largest, player){ //reduce the max for all player
    return player.reduce(function(largest, record){ //reduce the max for each player
      return (largest > record.wins ? largest : record.wins);
    }, largest);
  }, 0);

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Object.values(coach_wins).reduce(
  (result, player) => Math.max(result, player.reduce(
    (wins, winsPerYear) => Math.max(wins, winsPerYear.wins)
  , 0))
, 0); // --> 11
```

Answer (score 0):

If player’s individual arrays will always containing 2 that’s fine I guess but if it can be changed you can go to some thing like this. Bit of code but won’t put you in exceptions

```
function getMaxWins(){
    var maxWins = 0;
    for (var curPlayer in coach_wins) {

        //checking whether is it contains records
        var playerRecords = coach_wins[curPlayer];

        if(playerRecords){
            playerRecords.forEach(function (playerRecord_) {
                if(maxWins < playerRecord_.wins) maxWins = playerRecord_.wins;
            });
        }
    }
    return maxWins;
}

console.log(getMaxWins());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
var max = coach_wins[Object.keys(coach_wins)[0]][0].wins;
for (var player in coach_wins ) {
if (coach_wins.hasOwnProperty(player)) {
   var current_max = Math.max.apply(Math,coach_wins[player].map(function(o){return o.wins;}));
    max = current_max > max ? current_max:max;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, using a functional approach and ES6 syntax, you can do

```
Math.max(...[].concat(...Object.values(coach_wins).map(p=>p.map(g=>g.wins))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable set to `0`, use `Object.values()` to iterate values of object, `.forEach()` to iterate each array, if value of `wins` is greater than variable, set variable to value of `"wins"` property

```js
var coach_wins = {
  "player1": [
    {
      year: 2015,
      wins: 6
    },
    {
      year: 2016,
      wins: 6
    }
  ],
  "player2": [
    {
      year: 2015,
      wins: 11
    },
    {
      year: 2016,
      wins: 6
    }
  ]
};

let res; 

Object.values(coach_wins)
.forEach(prop => 
  prop.forEach(({wins}) => {
    if (!res || wins > res) res = wins
  })
);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

An expected result object would have been appreciated but I am guessing this is what you are looking for:

```
var result = {};

for(var player in coach_wins){
      result[player] = coach_wins[player].reduce((max, value) => {return value.wins>max?value.wins:max}, 0);
}
```